# ActionScript 3: waiting for user input in the middle of a complicated chain of actions

Tags: actionscript-3

I'm attempting to write a roguelike game in ActionScript 3. In this genre of game, characters and items interact in complicated and unpredictable ways, such that long chains of in-game occurrences can happen in the space of a single turn, each one resulting from the last and often happening before the previous one is properly finished taking its course. A problem seems to arise when I find, in the middle of such a mess, that I need to prompt the player for input and act on it immediately, before anything else continues happening.

If the UI were running on a separate thread such that the player could enter input and I could receive it without having to return from the entire stack of functions currently executing, then the sane way would be to simply call (from within whatever monumental nesting of function calls I happen to be inside) a function that waits for player input and then acts on it. But in AS3, this isn't possible; a function that waits for input before returning would simply cause the program to hang.

In response to this sort of problem, people say that the correct solution is to break up my operations into pieces so that I can wait for user input and then resume what I was doing. This is lovely and works gracefully for the trivial examples that are usually provided with such suggestions, but in a case like this, where unpredictable and often random occurrences can lead to chains of dozens of complicated events at one time, any of which can suddenly require user input at any moment, the notion of "resume what I was doing" seems like a Herculean task.

Am I left with no other choice but to store everything that happens in the game as a data structure that describes all of the details of the occurrence including how far it has progressed up to this point, so that I can suddenly quit what I was doing to wait for player input and then reconstruct the previous state of things, no matter how elaborate it may have been? The cumbersomeness of this task, in comparison to the ability to simply call a "get_input" function from anywhere and then go on my merry way, seems enough to dissuade me or anyone from using AS3. What am I missing? Is there a way of going about this that won't drive me insane, or should I just take this as a hint that AS3 is the wrong tool for the job?

Comment: I don't have a good direct answer to a way to do this one call synchronously but something you may be able to benefit from that's fairly new to AS3 is Workers, this is essentially the most I've seen offered up in terms of doing things on a separate Thread though I know from reading about the implementation that it's not as flexible as say Java threads there are some tighter limitations in the interest of keeping things simpler.

Comment: Another option I could see is having the game logic execute based upon a timer and simply stopping that timer and restarting it appropriately, but this may cause issues with the whole issue of these processes that you want to pause half way through since it would only allow the full execution of some function or no call to it depending on if the timer is running or not.

Answer (score 0):

About data structures - I think yes, you are doing it right. About "instant" requests for user input - you should have a quantum of time defined somewhere, anything that lasts less than this is considered an instant event, and should never require user input in lines of "continue?". Now, you want to have an event to trigger more events that would be shorter than main event, this can be done, and AS3 is normal for this type of event handling - but, in order to make player able to provide input, you have to release enterFrame listener or whatever process you use to process your event chain. So, for example, you can do like this:

```
var userInputRequested:Boolean=false;
while (!userInputRequested && (yourEventsToBeProcessed>0)) {
    userInputRequested=processOneTurnOfOneEvent();
}
```

Obviously, your game should then be able to process an event for a quantum of time at once, say an event "your character is putting on armor", as I've seen a roguelike with a lengthy event like this. Okay, this event is pushed into your event chain, yourEventsToBeProcessed is now nonzero. This loop works processing one dressing event along with counting game time (!!! if you miss this, you're in big trouble. It should be in line of "when we reached the last event to process this quantum, advance one quantum and start from first event") until the event successfully finished, or another random event will pop up ("a kobold enters view!" - it might not require user input, but "a kobold is in attack range" might). Basically, the event "move your world" is always active in that chain, but is not counted in the counter that's checked in that loop, otherwise your player will eternally wait for the world. Now, such an event is visible to the player, and if "processOneTurnOfOneEvent()" will return true, the loop ends, the enterFrame listener might then provide a way for the user to input something, and wait patiently until input will be received.